# Make an AppleScript Dialog Box the only object that can be clicked

Tags: applescript, dialog

I've created an AppleScript which is created by a shell script. When it is created (and automatically executed) it opens a dialog box. I want the dialog box to be the only thing that is able to be clicked on. Nothing else should be able to be clicked on or opened. 


I greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: Apple aren't going to let you stop a user from using his computer - it's not Windows! http://stackoverflow.com/q/21433486/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell okay how about making the dialog box the size of the entire screen. Just any way of making it the only action possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I don't think that this is possible but I recommend, 1. Download Xcode, 2. Make a "Cocoa AppleScript" Application and you can customize the window as a Button etc...